# How to make react-app to recognize "1n" as BigInt

Tags: reactjs, plugins, bigint

I have a package that does some calculations using BigInt.

When loaded into react, I get an error:
"Identifier directly after number", pointing to the "n" after the number.

If I change the code to `BigInt(96)` instead of `96b` it works, which means the code recognize BigInts correctly, just fails to parse the literals.

There is a plugin for that, but adding this to my `.babelrc` doesn't seem to change react's behaviour:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-bigint"]
}
```

Comment: I thought the new bigInt primitive is used as `96n` instead of `96b`. https://v8.dev/features/bigint. And I tried with `console.log(1345345435435n * 1n)`, works in node compiler.